# My class book says that arrays are set with const variables. What are some problems I could encounter when I use non const variables?

Tags: c++, arrays

The C++ book I'm reading tells us that arrays are to be set with constant variables, but I wanted to let user input instruct the size of the array, and it worked. Are there are problems I should worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you declare the array?

You can create an array with a size based on a variable if you declare it this way:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
// (assert size is > 0 and < some really big number here)
int* myarray = new int[size];
// Do stuff with it here...
delete [] myarray;  // Don't forget this.
```

and that will work just fine. You *shouldn't* be able to create an array this way:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int myarray[size]; // should break with an ugly compiler error.
```

If you did the second method and it worked, then you have a strange compiler, and you should not count on it working when you use other compilers on other platforms.

Comment: The way I used was the latter. I'm not sure what "int*" is, all variables I have used up till this point have not included an asterisk.

Comment: @Justin, It's a pointer, and you can use it to point to the start of an array. It is ok that you don't understand the syntax (trust me--you'll learn soon enough). For now, know that the first way is the correct way to do what you want to do, and you shouldn't get in the habit of doing the second way.

Comment: Okay Thanks! And you're right, we cover pointers in the next chapter!

Comment: @Stargazer712 you forgot about `delete`. Such code will have memory leak.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan, I omitted it simply because I was trying to quickly demonstrate the creation of an array, not necessarily the full lifecycle. But you are absolutely right that `delete [] myarray` is crucial to perform at some point after running that code.

Comment: @Stargazer712 then why not add it to answer?

Answer (score 3):

Using C arrays is not a best practice. Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)  instead.

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;
std::vector<int> vec(n);//declares int array size of n;
```

to use `std::vector` you should include `<vector>`.

Also vector is much more flexible. For example you can change size of vector at runtime.

```
std::vector<int> vec;//declares empty vector

int some_numb;

while(std::cin>>some_numb)//read untill end of file
   vec.push_back(some_numb);//add element at the end of array;
```

`Edit:` If you still want to use C style array instead of vector, here is syntax.

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;
int * arr = new int[n];
```

But remember, that after creating array this way you should also delete it manually. Here is syntax.

```
delete []arr;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: While that may be helpful in the future, I don't know what it is, and I would like to stick with arrays because I will be required to work with them in class.

Comment: I have to agree that while using a `vector` is safer, it does nothing to answer his question.

Comment: @Andrew @Stargazer712 Why teach bad habits new programmers? Sourly after getting some experience every C++ programmer should learn what is C style array.

Comment: @Ashot, typically when programming you start from the bottom up. You should understand arrays before you learn vectors even though vectors are preferred in most cases. Similar to how in calculus they teach solving derivatives my limit first even though you'll almost never use that technique once you learn the rules. It gives you a foundation of understanding with which to build upon. Further, learning the wrong way first means you hopefully understand _why_ it's wrong.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Have a look at this http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#simple-program. Even Stroustrup, author of the language is suggesting to teach `std::vector` to novices and not C style array.

Comment: @Ashot, that doesn't mean you can't still teach them regular arrays first. Believe me, I think that everyone should learn vectors early on, but they should also be taught C arrays first so they understand them.

Comment: @Ashot, because if avoiding a direct use of memory was the goal, then he/she would be learning how to program in a managed environment instead. Learning C/C++ without learning about memory is like learning Java without learning OOP.

Comment: @Stargazer712 I'm not saying, that one shouldn't learn C style arrays. I'm saying, that novice first should learn how to program, what is array, how he can use it, how to write algorithms. And only after learning programming bases  you should dig deeper and learn  that. I have learned C style arrays first, and I don't think that it was right.

Comment: @Ashot, well, not really. What you're basically saying is that someone should learn a managed language first (Java, Python, C#, etc...), and only take on C/C++ later. I don't feel that has to be the case. Learn what you want to learn imho.

Comment: @Stargazer712  there is no language C/C++. I know C, I know C++. C and C++ are completely different languages. And if something is compiling in C and C++, it doesn't mean,  that this code is correct C and C++ code. Lot of correct C code is buggy C++ code due to exceptions etc.. So if you picked  C, learn C and C style programming. But if you picked to learn C++ don't learn C first, learn how to do that in C++.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different kinds of array allocation techniques, the first is **static**, where you know the size of the array when the program is compiled. Since you have to know the size when you compile, it's a good idea to make the size integer `const` to prevent it from accidentally being changed, which could cause your program to crash:

```
const int myarray_size = 10;
int myarray[myarray_size];
```

The second is **dynamic**, where you don't know the size of the array at compile time, only at run time. You have to call the `new` operator here to tell the operating system to allocate memory for the array:

```
int myarray_size;
cin >> myarray_size;
int* myarray = new int[myarray_size];
```

You also must call `delete[] myarray` later when you're done using the array.

The following is an example of why using `const` for static array sizes is good practice:

```
const int myarray_size = 10;
cin >> myarray_size;  // This won't compile because you're trying to change a const
int myarray[myarray_size];
```

Whereas the following might compile (depending on your setup), but could easily cause your program to crash when run:

```
int myarray_size;
cin >> myarray_size;
int myarray[myarray_size]
```

Comment: `delete myarray` is undefined behavior. Should be `delete []myarray;`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add any checks the user could potentially create a huge array, which could consume a lot of memory.